# How to get next value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to produce a HTML list grouped by "groupName" from the array below.

```
array (size=30)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'groupOrder' => string '1' (length=1)
      'groupName' => string 'Class' (length=11)
      'txt' => string '............' (length=32)
      'ID' => string '6' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'groupOrder' => string '1' (length=1)
      'groupName' => string 'Size' (length=11)
      'txt' => string '..................' (length=34)
      'ID' => string '6' (length=1)
  2 => 
      ...
```

So I'd like produce something like this pseudo list:

- groupName

  - txt
  - txt
  - txt
- next GroupName

  - txt
  - txt 
    ...

So my code looks like this

```
foreach ($datafeed as $val => $row) {
       if (($datafeed[$val]['groupName']) == next($datafeed[$val]['groupName'])) {
           //same group - do nothing
       } else {
            echo $datafeed[$val]['groupName'];
       }

       echo "<li>".$row['txt']. "</li>";
}
```

But I'm getting errors about "next() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given".

I've tried all sorts of different syntax, but I'm not making much progress. How do I compare two values in a nested array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted the meaning of the function `next()`: you cannot query it for an array element. It manipulates the internal array pointer tied with the array itself, not with some its element. From [the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php):

```
Every array has an internal pointer to its "current" element, which is initialized to the first element inserted into the array.
```

and see also [a description of `next`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

Since the `foreach` loop crucially depends on the value of the array pointer, messing with the array pointer will ruin the loop: you probably see every second element in the loop, because at every iteration once `next()` is called by your `foreach` loop and then once by yourself.

The simplest thing for you is probably to use the old good `for` loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < length ($array); $i++)
{
    if ($i == 0 || $array[$i] != $array[$i - 1])
        echo "New group!\n";

    echo $array[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you'd be better off restructuring your array so that they're grouped, and you don't need to perform any logic within the loop to check the `groupName`. Currently, you're relying on the next `groupName` to match the current `groupName`, but if they're not sequential, they won't be grouped.

You could do something like this:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($datafeed as $feed) {
    $output[$feed['groupName']][] = $feed;
}
```

#### [Here's a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/vbMVIT)

Comment: Good point, although in this case I take care of the grouping in the SQL Query that supplies the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `next` inside a `foreach` loop anyway, since you'll get conflicting array pointer movements. Simply *store the last* value:

```
$last = null;
foreach (...) {
    if ($last != $row['current']) {
        // new group
    }
    $last = $row['current'];
    ...
}
```